# DOM: Does div have a text object child node by default?

Tags: dom

HTML:

```
<div id="Box" style="height: 100px; width= 100px; background-color: red;">
 <img src="someImg.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

Thatsit. I have a simple div in the HTML file. Now, in the javascript file I write

```
window.onload = initAll;

function initAll(){
document.getElementById("Box").onclick = childNodes;
}

function childNodes(){

for(var n = 0 ; n < this.childNodes.length; n++){
alert(this.childNodes.item(n));
}
```

Now, here shouldn't I see just one alert box(because the div element has just one child that is an image). Instead, I am getting 3 alert boxes. First and third alert 'Object text' and second alerts "Obkect HTMLImageElement". Why is it so?

Comment: And this is the difference between `childNodes` and `children`.

Comment: I am new to all this. Never noticed the difference. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: `childNodes` include text nodes and comment nodes as well as element nodes. `children` include only element nodes. http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Wtg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have empty space around your `img` tag which is identified as a text node.